# Angular js ng show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Onclick i have to show one section and hide another one using angular concept.

I have tried these

```
<div data-ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">Apps</div>
<div data-ng-click="showDetails1 = ! showDetails1">Favorites</div>
<div data-ng-click="showDetails2 = ! showDetails2">Search</div>


<section id="workbench-search" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }">search</section>

    <section id="workbench-favorites" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails1 }">fav</section>

    <section id="workbench-apps" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails2 }">apps</section>
```

But onclick it is not hiding the other one ,

can you suggest in angular way .New to angular concept

Comment: Do you have `data-ng-app` within a containing `div` or in the `body` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails; showDetails1 = false; showDetails2 = false;">Apps {{showDetails}}</div>
<div ng-click="showDetails1 = !showDetails1; showDetails = false; showDetails2 = false;">Favorites {{showDetails1}}</div>
<div ng-click="showDetails2 = !showDetails2; showDetails = false; showDetails1 = false;">Search {{showDetails2}}</div>


<section id="workbench-search" ng-class="{ 'hidden': !showDetails }">search</section>

<section id="workbench-favorites" ng-class="{ 'hidden': !showDetails1 }">fav</section>

<section id="workbench-apps" ng-class="{ 'hidden': !showDetails2 }">apps</section>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MTyV9D?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.
Try this

```
<div data-ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails;showDetails1 = false;showDetails2 = false">Apps</div>
<div data-ng-click="showDetails1 = ! showDetails1;showDetails = false;showDetails2 = false">Favorites</div>
<div data-ng-click="showDetails2 = ! showDetails2;showDetails = false;showDetails1 = false">Search</div>


<section id="workbench-search" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }">search</section>

<section id="workbench-favorites" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails1 }">fav</section>

<section id="workbench-apps" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails2 }">apps</section>
```